# When moving from Spring Boot 3.1.0 to 3.1.1, JOIN queries break

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm migrating from Spring Boot 3.1.0 to 3.1.1, just a simple patch version upgrade.

But it incorrectly starts using JOIN on a table instead of the defined LEFT JOIN. This means I get fewer results because the foreign key is optional.

Repo:

```
@Query("""
    SELECT ak FROM ApiKey ak
    LEFT JOIN ak.role r
    WHERE ak.projectId = :projectId
    """)
Page<ApiKey> find(@Param("projectId") UUID projectId, Pageable pageable);
```

The reason we LEFT JOIN on `role` is because the pageable can contain a sort on `role.name`

However, now the following query is generated:

```
select a1_0.id,a1_0.created_date,a1_0.db_version,a1_0.expiry_date,a1_0.last_used,a1_0.name,a1_0.project_id,a1_0.public_part,a1_0.role_id,a1_0.secret_key_hash,a1_0.updated_date from api_key a1_0 join role r2_0 on r2_0.id=a1_0.role_id where a1_0.project_id=? order by r2_0.name offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
```

Which has a regular join, which is clearly wrong.
Is there anything I can do here except rewrite to SQL?

Comment: Have you tried updating Hibernate to see if it would help?

Comment: You could try to override the hibernate version that is defined in the 3.1.1 spring-boot-dependencies to be the one from 3.1.0 spring-boot-bom. Have you verified that this is an actual spring problem or is it a hibernate problem? Have you tried creating the jpa query using the EntityManager directly?

Comment: @JCompetence there is no newer version of Hibernate yet, 6.2.5 is the latest and greatest.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I'm guessing it's a Hibernate problem, but then again can't make it work by defining an override of the Hibernate version so maybe there's something else that's fishy. I'll go and try making the query with the entityManager.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker when creating a query entirely through the EntityManager the query is correct. But unfortunately then we'd need to also do the sorting and paging manually, which I'm trying to avoid, since there's a few 100 queries like this that possibly sort on data from another table that is optional.

Comment: I submitted a bug report at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16856

Comment: The generated query uses the role table only for the `order by` clause. That could possibly be the case. Where does that come from? It's not in your query. Also, why are you even joining on the role table if you're not using it? If you only want to make sure the records are fetched, a `JOIN FETCH` is perhaps better.

Comment: @RobSpoor the pageable can contain a sort on role.name. I want nothing from this table except the sorting. I can already get the role id from the api key entity anyway and that's all the client calling this endpoint needs. This all worked fine 1 patch version ago btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow-up from ticket:

This is actually not Hibernate but Spring Data removing the `left join`, and it apparently does that because it cannot see its purpose, as the sort param is not called the same as the alias in the `left join`. Hibernate then adds a regular `join` automatically later to be able to sort on the actual `role.name` sort. I guess it does this by finding the `role` as a field name in ApiKey.

What I would consider a bug is that it doesn't use `left join` but `join`, since now the data is automatically restricted because of a sort. It's also a big change to make in a small patch release. But at least the easy solution here would be to name the alias the same as the field in the entity. Especially if your pageable is constructed by a client (like in our case) and they wouldn't want to use alias shorthands for their sort params.

Answer (score -1):

If Role table is seprate table than you should try this.

```
SELECT 
    ak
FROM
    ApiKey ak
        LEFT JOIN
    Role r ON ak.role = r.id
WHERE
    ak.id = 1;
```

If you want to apply leftjoin on same table than try this

```
SELECT 
    ak
FROM
    ApiKey ak
        LEFT JOIN
    ApiKey ak1 ON ak.role = ak1.role
WHERE
    ak.id = :projectId;
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the ON clause with a JPQL join, it can be determined from the metadata.

Comment: Thanks but this seems a little too hacky and I would have to do it in tons of places, even if it does work.